# Index out of bounds in a txt File

Tags: c#, arrays, file, limit, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm just starting with learning how to Write in and Read .txt Files. I'm currently working on a Program that will save Usernames and Passwords in two documents. But the method for adding a new Username always says that the Index is out of Bounds. I already tried lots of things, and the only thing i can think of is using a List, which isnt accpeted by File.WriteAllLines. (Also the Files are already in the directory because I haven't added code that creates them yet.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Accountsystem
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //Choose Register or Login
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome!");
        Console.WriteLine("Register = r     Login = l");
        string rlcheck = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (rlcheck)
        {
            case "r":
                Register();
                break;
            case "l":
                Login();
                break;
            default:
                Main();
                break;
        }
    }
    static void Register()
    {
        //Choose Username and check if already available
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Username:");
        string Username = Console.ReadLine();
        foreach (string Usernam in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1ru\Desktop\Ich\Programming\Usernames.txt"))
        {
            if (Username == Usernam)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Username taken");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Register();
            }
        }

        //Choose Password
        Console.WriteLine("Password:");
        string Password = Console.ReadLine();

        //Find out Amount of already existing Users, to know where to add new one
        string[] Users = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1ru\Desktop\Ich\Programming\Usernames.txt");
        int Index = 0;
        foreach (string User in Users)
        {
            Index++;
        }

        //Write new Username into File
        string[] Usernames = new string[File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1ru\Desktop\Ich\Programming\Usernames.txt").Length + 1];
        Usernames = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1ru\Desktop\Ich\Programming\Usernames.txt");
        Usernames[Index] = Username;
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\1ru\Desktop\Ich\Programming\Usernames.txt", Usernames);

        //Write new Password into File
        string[] Passwords = new string[File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1ru\Desktop\Ich\Programming\Passwords.txt").Length + 1]; 
        Passwords = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1ru\Desktop\Ich\Programming\Passwords.txt");
        Passwords[Index] = Password;
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\1ru\Desktop\Ich\Programming\Passwords.txt", Passwords);
    }
    //No use yet
    static void Login()
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: The line `Usernames = File.ReadAllLines...` will overwrite your carefully allocated array. Better use a List instead of an array. Much easier to add new elements.

Comment: If `File.WriteAllLines()` doesn't take a List, you can use `.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these three lines:

```
    string[] Usernames = new string[File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1ru\Desktop\Ich\Programming\Usernames.txt").Length + 1];
    Usernames = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1ru\Desktop\Ich\Programming\Usernames.txt");
    Usernames[Index] = Username;
```

If the file contains N lines, the first code line will allocate a string array with N+1 entries. But you immediately overwrite it with the result of `File.ReadAllLines` which is a string array of N lines.
This is why the last line fails, as `Index` is equal to N.

It is better to use a `List<string>` instead of a `string[]` as it makes adding entries much easier:

```
var usernames = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1ru\Desktop\Ich\Programming\Usernames.txt").ToList();
usernames.Add(username);
```